# Graylog Collector Connection Refused

Tags: tcp, graylog2, graylog

I am trying to create a Graylog Server - Graylog Collector setup, where the graylog collector collects the syslog files on one machine and ships them to the server.

I have used the AWS AMI to create the Graylog Server and it is working as expected.

I installed a Graylog Collector on the same machine and I am able to see it in the list of sources for that instance.

My problem is when I try and connect to a remote Graylog Collector.

The Graylog Collector configuration file looks like this:

```
server-url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12900/"

inputs {  
  syslog {
    type = "file"
    path = "/var/log/syslog"
  }     
}

outputs {
  graylog-server {
    type = "gelf"
    host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    port = 12201
  } 
}
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the private IP address of the graylog server I am attempting to connect to.

An extract from the configuration of the graylog server is:

```
rest_listen_uri = http://0.0.0.0:12900/
```

And the security groups for both instances are as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Type            | Protocol        | Port Range   |  Source    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom TCP Rule | TCP             | 12201        |  0.0.0.0/0 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom TCP Rule | TCP             | 12900        |  0.0.0.0/0 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I look at the logs for the graylog collector, I get the following messages:

```
2015-11-14T23:41:33.948+0000 ERROR [gelfTcpTransport-1-1] gelfclient.transport.GelfTcpTransport - Connection failed: Connection refused: /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12201
2015-11-14T23:41:34.949+0000 ERROR [gelfTcpTransport-1-1] gelfclient.transport.GelfTcpTransport - Connection failed: Connection refused: /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12201
2015-11-14T23:41:35.951+0000 ERROR [gelfTcpTransport-1-1] gelfclient.transport.GelfTcpTransport - Connection failed: Connection refused: /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12201
2015-11-14T23:41:36.953+0000 ERROR [gelfTcpTransport-1-1] gelfclient.transport.GelfTcpTransport - Connection failed: Connection refused: /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12201
2015-11-14T23:41:37.956+0000 ERROR [gelfTcpTransport-1-1] gelfclient.transport.GelfTcpTransport - Connection failed: Connection refused: /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12201
2015-11-14T23:41:38.698+0000 WARN  [HeartbeatService RUNNING] collector.heartbeat.HeartbeatService - Unable to send heartbeat to Graylog server: ConnectException: Connection refused
```

(again xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the private IP address of the graylog server I am attempting to connect to)

I have run a traceroute between the 2 machines on port 12201 and port 12900 without any problems.

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing in my configuration to allow these 2 to connect?

Both are running Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks,

Seán

Comment: Update - I have I have created a GELF TCP Input on my graylog server on port 12201.

The error message I'm now receiving is:

2015-11-16T09:35:04.689+0000 WARN  [HeartbeatService RUNNING] collector.heartbeat.HeartbeatService - Unable to send heartbeat to Graylog server: ConnectException: Connection refused

So it looks like it has worked to an extent but I'm still not able to view the collector running on the client in the list of collectors on the System > Collectors page.

I guess I could just disable heartbeat registration in the configuration for the graylog collector (but I'd rather not).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. In my case, the Graylog server is instanced locally, using a vagrant virtual machine. I'm researching, if I have a solution I'will post it here. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the settings in the Graylog Web , `"System -> Inputs"`  menu, edit the input settings that listen from port 12201 (in my case is called `"Appliance Gelf UDP"` ), and change the `"Bind Adress"` to your private IP. In my case , that everything is in localhost (the collector and the vagrant virtual machine containing the Graylog server) , I have written `"127.0.0.1"`, and the `"HeartbeatService RUNNING] collector.heartbeat.HeartbeatService - Unable to send heartbeat to Graylog server: ConnectException: Connection refused"` error message have dissapear from the Graylog Collector's log.

This is the STDOUT output of a healthy collector starting:

```
2015-12-18T12:26:24.027+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Starting Collector v0.4.1 (commit 36a0856)
2015-12-18T12:26:24.032+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Running on Windows 8.1 Windows 8.1 6.3 (amd64)
2015-12-18T12:26:25.311+0100 INFO  [main] collector.utils.CollectorId - Collector ID: ff0f70f5-2d48-4b5c-9943-88031ea5e0fc
2015-12-18T12:26:25.349+0100 INFO  [main] outputs.gelf.GelfOutput - Starting GELF transport: org.graylog2.gelfclient.GelfConfiguration@7ca65d82
2015-12-18T12:26:25.761+0100 INFO  [gelfTcpTransport-1-1] gelfclient.transport.GelfTcpTransport - Channel disconnected!
2015-12-18T12:26:25.761+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Service RUNNING: BufferProcessor [RUNNING]
2015-12-18T12:26:25.761+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Service RUNNING: FileObserver [RUNNING]
2015-12-18T12:26:25.761+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Service RUNNING: MemoryReporterService [RUNNING]
2015-12-18T12:26:25.761+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Service RUNNING: MetricService [RUNNING]
2015-12-18T12:26:25.762+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Service RUNNING: HeartbeatService [RUNNING]
2015-12-18T12:26:25.764+0100 INFO  [main] cli.commands.Run - Service RUNNING: GelfOutput{port='12201', id='gelf-tcp', client-send-buffer-size='-1', host='127.0.0.1', inputs='', client-reconnect-delay='1000', client-connect-timeout='5000', client-tcp-no-delay='true', client-queue-size='512'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heartbeat error is related to the registration of graylog-collector with the graylog-server. The collector needs to register with the Graylog server so that it can appear in the System->Collector menu of the web interface.
In the graylog-collector configuration file set 
"enable-registration = false" (without quotes)
as global configuration to remove this heartbeat error.
This will remove the heartbeat error and the logs will still be going on the graylog sever without any issue.